# Python Airflow - Return result from PythonOperator

Tags: python, airflow

I have written a DAG with multiple PythonOperators

```
task1 = af_op.PythonOperator(task_id='Data_Extraction_Environment',
                          provide_context=True,
                          python_callable=Task1, dag=dag1)

def Task1(**kwargs):
    return(kwargs['dag_run'].conf.get('file'))
```

From PythonOperator i am calling "Task1" method. That method is returning a value,that value i need to pass to the next PythonOperator.How can i get the value from the "task1" variable or How can i get the value which is returned from Task1 method?

updated :

```
    def Task1(**kwargs):
          file_name = kwargs['dag_run'].conf.get[file]
          task_instance = kwargs['task_instance']
          task_instance.xcom_push(key='file', value=file_name) 
          return file_name

  t1 = PythonOperator(task_id = 'Task1',provide_context=True,python_callable=Task1,dag=dag)

  t2 =   BashOperator(
      task_id='Moving_bucket', 
      bash_command='python /home/raw.py {{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='Task1',key='file') }} ',
      dag=dag,
    )

t2.set_upstream(t1)
```

Comment: Yes...Yes i am executing in the same fashion...i have updated the code

Comment: At first i didn't add that manually...it gave "None" then i have added,In both the cases value is "None"

Comment: Yes..i checked that..... It is printing the value in the log....

Comment: I am executing DAG from the URL like "http://localhost:8080/admin/rest_api/api?api=trigger_dag&dag_id=Data&conf={%22file%22:%22data.csv%22}"

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You might want to check out Airflow's XCOM: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html

If you return a value from a function, this value is stored in xcom. In your case, you could access it like so from other Python code:

```
task_instance = kwargs['task_instance']
task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='Task1')
```

or in a template like so:

```
{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='Task1') }}
```

If you want to specify a key you can push into XCOM (being inside a task):

```
task_instance = kwargs['task_instance']
task_instance.xcom_push(key='the_key', value=my_str)
```

Then later on you can access it like so:

```
task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='my_task', key='the_key')
```

**EDIT 1**

Follow-up question: *Instead of using the value in another function how can i pass the value to another PythonOperator like - "t2 = "BashOperator(task_id='Moving_bucket', bash_command='python /home/raw.py "%s" '%file_name, dag=dag)" --- i want to access file_name which is returned by "Task1". How can this will be acheived?*

First of all, it seems to me that the value is, in fact, *not* being passed to another `PythonOperator` but to a `BashOperator`.

Secondly, this is already covered in my answer above. The field `bash_command` is templated (see `template_fields` in the source: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py). Hence, we can use the templated version:

```
BashOperator(
  task_id='Moving_bucket', 
  bash_command='python /home/raw.py {{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='Task1') }} ',
  dag=dag,
)
```

**EDIT 2**

Explanation:
Airflow works like this: It will execute Task1, then populate xcom and then execute the next task. So for your example to work you need Task1 executed first and then execute Moving_bucket downstream of Task1.

Since you are using a return function, you could also omit the `key='file'` from `xcom_pull` and not manually set it in the function.

Comment: Instead of using the value in another function how can i pass the value to another PythonOperator like - "t2 =  "BashOperator(task_id='Moving_bucket',
                 bash_command='python /home/raw.py "%s" '%file_name,
                 dag=dag)" --- i want to access file_name which is returned by "Task1". How can this will be acheived?

Comment: I have updated the question when i am doing that i am getting "NONE".when i am printing the file_name,it is printing the file_name. am i missing anything there?

Comment: Your bash operator does not work for me. It works replacing the single quotes by double quotes: task_ids="Task1"  (note: My bash command is echo.)