# Airflow - Run each python function separately

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have the airflow below script that runs all python scripts as one function. I would like to have each the python functions to run individually so that I could keep track of each function and their status.

```
## Third party Library Imports

import psycopg2
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
#from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import io


# Following are defaults which can be overridden later on
default_args = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2018, 1, 23, 12),
'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
'email_on_failure': False,
'email_on_retry': False,
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG('sample_dag', default_args=default_args, catchup=False, schedule_interval="@once")


#######################
## Login to DB


def db_log():
    global db_con
    try:
    db_con = psycopg2.connect(
    " dbname = 'name' user = 'user' password = 'pass' host = 'host' port = 'port' sslmode = 'require' ")
    except:
        print("Connection Failed.")
        print('Connected successfully')
    return (db_con)

def insert_data():
    cur = db_con.cursor()
    cur.execute("""insert into tbl_1 select id,bill_no,status from tbl_2 limit 2;""")


def job_run():
    db_log()
    insert_data()



##########################################

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='DB_Connect',
    python_callable=job_run,
    # bash_command='python3 ~/airflow/dags/sample.py',
    dag=dag)

t1
```

The above script works just fine but would like to split this by function to keep better track. Could anyone assist on this. Tnx..

Updated Code (version 2):

```
## Third party Library Imports

import psycopg2
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
#from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import io


# Following are defaults which can be overridden later on
default_args = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2018, 1, 23, 12),
'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
'email_on_failure': False,
'email_on_retry': False,
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG('sample_dag', default_args=default_args, catchup=False, schedule_interval="@once")


#######################
## Login to DB


def db_log(**kwargs):
    global db_con
    try:
    db_con = psycopg2.connect(
    " dbname = 'name' user = 'user' password = 'pass' host = 'host' port = 'port' sslmode = 'require' ")
    except:
        print("Connection Failed.")
        print('Connected successfully')
        task_instance = kwargs['task_instance']
        task_instance.xcom_push(value="db_con", key="db_log")
        return (db_con)

def insert_data(**kwargs):
    v1 = task_instance.xcom_pull(key="db_con", task_ids='db_log')
    return (v1)
    cur = db_con.cursor()
    cur.execute("""insert into tbl_1 select id,bill_no,status from tbl_2 limit 2;""")

#def job_run():
#    db_log()
#    insert_data()


##########################################

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='Connect',
    python_callable=db_log,provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)

t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='Query',
    python_callable=insert_data,provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)


t1 >> t2
```

Comment: @tobi6, get an error on the bash_command syntax (2nd last line of the Updated code). Could you please advice where have I gone wrong. Tnx.

Comment: @tobi6

Error message is 
bash_command='python3 ~/airflow/dags/sample.py {{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_id='job_run', key='dwh_connection')}}',dag=dag,)
                                                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

How do I fix this. Could you please advice.. Tnx

Comment: @tobi6, I thought we need to pass the insert_data in the same manner and hence used it this way. For the bash operator I am not sure on how to pass the login details (datawarehouse_login() ) to be referred by multiple functions in the script. Could you please advice on this. Tnx..

Comment: @tobi6, thanks I am trying to correlate each of the these points into a working script. My question is we would need to have the bash_command to pass in the "task_instance.xcom_pull" command right. Also if the job has different sub-functions how could we keep track of each of the functions. Since from what I understand bash operator is called just once in the above code. Could you please clarify on the above. Tnx..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171965/discussion-between-dark-horse-and-tobi6).

Comment: @tobi6, I have modified the script based on the the previous comments and documentation (Kindly refer to Updated Code (version 2) in the initial message). I am currently getting an error, **Subtask: NameError: name 'task_instance' is not defined**. Could you please advice on what's wrong in the above code. Tnx..

Comment: Again, please ask a new question why this error comes up. I can already see what's wrong but it is not helpful for others if your question keeps evolving and there are many, many comments (usually those informal get deleted later by the commentor)

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions for this:

**A) Create several tasks per function**

The tasks in Airflow are being called in separate processes. Variables which get defined as `global` won't work since the second task can usually not see into the variables of the first task.

Introducing: XCOM. This is a feature of Airflow and we answered a few questions for this already, for example here (with examples): [Python Airflow - Return result from PythonOperator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149085/python-airflow-return-result-from-pythonoperator/50149522#50149522)

**EDIT**

You have to *provide context* and *pass the context along* as written in the examples. For your example, this would mean:

- add `provide_context=True,` to your `PythonOperator`
- change the signature of   `job_run` to `def job_run(**kwargs):`
- pass the kwargs to data_warehouse_login with `data_warehouse_login(kwargs)` inside the function

**B) Create one complete function**

In this very scenario I'd still remove the global (just call `insert_data`, call `data_warehouse_login` from within and return the connection) and use just one task.

If an error occurs, throw an exception. Airflow will handle these just fine. Just make sure to put appropriate messages in the exception and use the best exception type.