# Airflow, get current status of a task in current dag run

Tags: airflow

I have a task through which i write to db which tasks have been processed successfully. I am trying to get `TaskInstance.current_status()` from my python operator. However, i cannot seem to find a way to get TaskInstance successfully.
how to get the task instance, to pass to `TaskInstance()`?
I tried `task_id`, but it seems it cannot be string

Comment: Please show an example of what you've attempted

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149085/python-airflow-return-result-from-pythonoperator/50149522#50149522

Comment: @joeb, i tried using TaskInstance from airflow.models.
TaskInstance("task_id", execution_date). Can you suggest a way to get current status of a task(other than the one being executed) in the same dag run?

Answer (score 9):

Looks like it is fairly simple:

```
 from airflow.models import TaskInstance
 dag_instance = kwargs['dag']
 operator_instance = dag_instance.get_task("task_id")
 task_status = TaskInstance(operator_instance, execution_date).current_state()
```

Comment: Where did you get `kwargs` from?

Comment: @P.V. from the python function binded to the PythonOperator, if the operator has `provide_context=True`, the function will accept a **kwargs argument with extra context information for that task. Bonus, you can give extra context information with op_kwargs parameter

Comment: FYI, `execution_date` also comes from the context variable, in this case `kwargs['execution_date']`