# Python Airflow - How to get result of the task when declaring dag

Tags: python, airflow

I have written a DAG with multiple PythonOperators like this

```
def Task1:
    # Do something and return an array
    return ["a","b","c"]

def Task2:
    # Do something
    return

with DAG(
...
) as dag:
    task1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="task1_id",
        python_callable=Task1,
    )

    task1_result= # Result of task1
    
    for value in task1_result:
        t = PythonOperator(
            task_id=f"task2_id_{value}",
            python_callable=Task2
        task1 >> t
```

How can i get `task1_result` variable is value of `task1`. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149085/python-airflow-return-result-from-pythonoperator

Comment: You might be interested in [Dynamic Task Mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html) added in Airflow 2.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without context, but supposing that `Task1` returns just a simple list of results, without any complex logic, you could do this if you want to build your DAG dynamically:

```
def Task1:
    # Do something and return an array
    return ["a","b","c"]

def Task2:
    # Do something
    return

with DAG(
...
) as dag:
    task1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="task1_id",
        python_callable=Task1,
    )

    for value in Task1():
        t = PythonOperator(
            task_id=f"task2_id_{value}",
            python_callable=Task2
        task1 >> t
```