# How to write empty table if "from" clause does not match any result?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, google-bigquery, jinja2, airflow

I'm using Apache Airflow to build a pipeline that generate reports for each week of some project, according to its data tables.

My second task get proper data to generate a chart regarding last four weeks activity. However, for the first run, whose date is equals to my dag `start_start`, I get the following error, using [BigQueryOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py):

```
Error: FROM clause with table wildcards matches no table
```

Since, I'm trying to get a table that does not exist, using Jinja2 templating.

My code:

```
t2 = BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='create_agg_last_four_wks_prof',
    bql=None,
    bql="""
    #legacySql
    SELECT
        date_wk,
        mun,
        names,
        count(unique(if(plans>=1, cpf, 0))) as plans,
        count(unique(cpf)) as num_prof
    FROM
        TABLE_DATE_RANGE([kos.agg_wk_prof_],
            TIMESTAMP('{{ macros.ds_add(ds, -28) }}'),
            TIMESTAMP('{{ macros.ds_add(ds, -7) }}'))
    WHERE
        project = true
    GROUP BY
        date_wk, mun, names
    """,
    destination_dataset_table="xcfz-edu:kos.test_agg_last_four_wks_prof_{{ ds_nodash }}",
    write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
    dag=dag
```

So, I want know how to write a empty table if the from clause matches no results. It would be a workaround solution for my issue.

I know that I can create a [conditional task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43678408/how-to-create-a-conditional-task-in-airflow), but I'm seeking for a solution that does not change "what is already working". I mean, that does not change affect other tasks.

Is it even possible using SQL or/and Jinja2 statements?

Comment: I think you are just missing `macro.ds_format` because as far as I know Google BigQuery expects `YYYYMMDD` and not `YYYY-MM-DD` which  `ds_add` returns.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using standard SQL in BigQuery:

```
SELECT
    date_wk,
    mun,
    names,
    count(DISTINCT if(plans>=1, cpf, 0)) as plans,
    count(DISTINCT cpf) as num_prof
FROM
    `pdc.agg_wk_prof_*`
WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN
      FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 28 DAY)) AND
      FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AND
    project = true
GROUP BY
    date_wk, mun, names
```