# Can Airflow be used with a "cache key" approach

Tags: airflow, mwaa

Suppose I have an expensive task, such as running an ML job or an Athena query, that is schedule to run daily. I know that the results from the previous day can be re-used if nothing has changed. Additionally, I can detect if anything has changed using an SQL query.

Can Airflow tasks be composed to implement logic like this?

- For today's task run...
- Get the result of `SELECT MAX(last_updated) FROM items`

  - If the result matches yesterday's execution, then copy the previous day's results
  - Otherwise, run the expensive task

---

Note I am using Airflow `2.2.2` (MWAA)

Answer (score 0):

> Can Airflow tasks be composed to implement logic like this?

Yes. This can be achieved with the `BranchPythonOperator`. See [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43678408/how-to-create-a-conditional-task-in-airflow) for an example.

Reference: [BranchPythonOperator (Airflow)](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.2/_api/airflow/operators/python/index.html?highlight=branchpythonoperator#airflow.operators.python.BranchPythonOperator)